# Win 11 install has SSIDs I've connected to with other devices. How did this data make it's way to the system?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, iphone

I was recently out of town and brought only my iPhone, which was used to connect to two different hotel wifi networks. When I returned a few days ago I began a new build of a laptop - I completely wiped a Debian system and replaced with Windows 11 ( don't even ask ). After completing the install I sought to debug wifi issues and found SSIDs for the hotels I stayed at. I don't know what to make of this. What is the source and how did it arrive at a pristine system? There was no direct connection between iPhone and PC and the only connection would be via email - which I hadn't yet configured.

Comment: Any indirect connections? Same accounts, syncing via cloud etc? What does "debug wifi issues" mean i.e. how/where did you find the SSIDs? The iPhone is maybe sending probe requests which you then find in some network dump. Is it reproducible? Maybe test with an open wifi + your iPhone nearby?

Comment: Having issues with the motherboard wifi adapter so I used a USB wifi dongle and stumbled across the list of connections. The SSIDs were listed under "Manage known networks". I'm happy to reproduce but would like to know at least a couple of places to look before proceeding because it will be a PIA. I'm not at all paranoid but would very much like to understand both the how and the why of this. On it's face, this is fairly creepy.

Comment: And do you have your accounts synced between iPhone and Windows?

Comment: @JNR - [Edit] your question to address the feedback you have recieved.